# error: package com.amplifyframework.core.model.temporal does not exist --- Error using amplify Temporal

Tags: java, android, kotlin, aws-amplify

im trying use this library from Amplify in my android studio project
com.amplifyframework.core.model.temporal but i got this error

error: package com.amplifyframework.core.model.temporal does not exist

all the other libraries still working right, thats my build gradle implementation of amplify

```
//amplify
implementation 'com.amplifyframework:core:2.8.5'
coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.3'
```

compileOptions {
coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

i already tried change de amplify version, but dosent works

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: have u found solution ?